# Mimic str() from R

Tags: python, r

`str()` in R can print a summarized form of an object in a nested way.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/str-implementation-for-data-frames/

I am not able to find a way similar to `str()`. For example, `pprint` does not do so. The idea is to 1) show the content in a readable way, 2) but when it is too long, show some representatives). `print` can not do both 1 and 2. `pprint` can not do 2.

```
d = {}

import string
for x in string.ascii_lowercase:
    d[x] = range(1000)

print d
import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
```

Does anybody know something similar to `str()` in the sense that I mentioned above?

Comment: `repr()` perhaps? Honestly, I'm not sure I get your description of what you want...

Comment: `print` merely outputs data, it doesn't do any formatting. `print(stuff)` means `sys.stdout.write(str(stuff))`, so, it's `str` that does the formatting. You can customise what `str` returns for your class by using the `__str__` method. However, you can't easily change the representation of other objects as that'd require you to reimplement their `__str__`.

Comment: Can you show what the desired output should be for this Python example?

Comment: BTW, looking at the above `print` statement, it looks like you are learning the old Python 2. Don't bother with that, it's slowly being replaced by Python 3.

Comment: `pprint` _can_ do (2). It doesn't use the same rules as R for the builtin types, but it does collapse some kinds of data. It is configurable, but probably not far enough to do exactly what you want. There are third-party libraries on PyPI (no idea about the state of up-to-date/activity/etc. for any of them) that you may want to search for.

Comment: Meanwhile, usually, if you're doing the same kinds of work in Python you'd be doing in R, you'll be using numpy, and sometimes pandas. And they have their own rules for eliding giant arrays that are a lot closer to R's. You do have to make sure to distinguish the `str` (which is designed for friendly printing) from the `repr` (which is designed to usually give you an expression you can use to recreate the exact same array), but `print` uses the former, and it's what you want here.

Comment: To add to @abarnert's comment: `repr` in Python is equivalent to `dput` in R.